# Is JavaScript identity compare really needed here?

Tags: javascript

This is from Crockford's [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

```
var is_array = function (value) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]';
};
```

Would this code have worked just as well if he had used a simple equality compare `==` instead of the identity compare `===`?

My understanding of identity is that it allows you to check if a value is really set to something specific, and not just something equivalent.  For example:

`x == true`

Will evaluate to true if x is 1, or true, but

`x === true` will only be true if x is true.

Is it ever possible for the is_array function above to work with either `==` or `===`, but not the other?

Comment: Crockford advocates always using `===` instead of `==`, but this code should, *probably*, work (or fail) same with any of these operators.

Comment: Use `==` only when you **explicitly** want to enable type coercion. (which is practically never, btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case `==` and `===` will work identically.

There would be no real difference in this case because both sides of the quality test are already strings so the extra type conversion that `==` could do won't come into play here.  Since there's never any type conversion here, then `==` and `===` will generate the same result.

In my own personal opinion, I tend to use `===` unless I explicitly want to allow type conversion as I think there is less likelihood of getting surprised by some result.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. With `==` instead of `===` it should work fine.

`===` is a strict match, and will not return true for 'falsy' or 'truthy' values ([see this](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) for more details). Which shouldn't apply in this situation.